# using 2 certificate to secure a single website apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I currently have an apache http server version 2.2.0 with a self-signed sha-1 certificate. I need to migrate to a more modern trusted certificate. We have used our current certificate to generate client side certificates. My question is can I use two server certificates in parallel until such time as the existing client side certificates expire ? and if so how do I configure apache to do this ?

Comment: You don't intend to continue to validate the client certificates. So simply stop doing that when you switch out the server certificate.

Comment: Michael, we issue certificates to clients based on our server certificate, they are typically valid for one year, some who access our api are valid for longer, hence the need to still accept requests based on the old certificate.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use a single **server certificate** for your website with Apache 2.2

For client authentication though, you can use multiple CA certificates concurrently to validate client certificates.   Simply concatenate the various PEM-encoded CA Certificate files, in order of preference, to whatever file  your [SSLCACertificateFile](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcacertificatefile) directive points to.

Answer (score 0):

I would update the Server certificate with a Letsencrypt https://letsencrypt.org/ trusted and for free, and keep the selfsigned certificate to validate client certificates. If the selfsigned certificate is going to expire, create a new one to issue new client certificate and add both, the old and new, in a file pointed by the SSLCACertifcateFile directive